# IIS 8, Out of memory , MVC Web site

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, iis-7, out-of-memory, iis-8

We have an issue on Live site (MVC .Net).

1. Max users 25
2. After every 2-3 hours IIS memory usage peak to Max memory
3. And All users get  a exception saying "System Out Memory"
4. We then need to restart IIS and All work Well.

Let me know if any solution to fix this.

Comment: Without more information, the best answer is simply a list of guesses. Is there any more information you can tell us about your site?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your application if there is no memory leaks. Also IIS has this behavioir during DOS attack.

Also you can set automatic IIS reset after memory usage increased some amount